# Found type UU where "?T" was expected

Tags: coq, coq-unimath

I am trying to solve [a couple of exercises](https://github.com/UniMath/Schools/blob/master/2019-04-Birmingham/Part1_Spartan_Type_Theory/Spartan_exercises.v) in coq. However, with the following code:

```
Require Import UniMath.Foundations.PartD.

(** The following axiom allows us to inhabit any type.
    It is a way of indicating where you need to fill in
    your own solutions. Remove it once you're done with
    all the exercises. *)
Axiom fill_me : forall {X : UU}, X.

Theorem exercise_1_4 : ∑ A:UU, (A → empty).
Proof.
   exact fill_me.
Qed.
```

I get the error `Found type "UU" where "?T" was expected` at the line of the theorem statement.
I can replace `UU` by `Type` (which is definitionally equal, I believe), which allows me to start writing the proof, but then using `refine (tpair _ empty _).` in the proof gives the following (even more impressive-looking) error:

```
The term "∅" has type "UU" while it is expected to have type 
"?T" (unable to find a well-typed instantiation for 
"?T": cannot ensure that "Type" is a subtype of "UU").
```

Comment: What if you do `simple refine (tpair _ _ _)` and then `refine empty` in the first goal?  Do either of these give error messages?

Comment: The first one is fine, but the second one gives an error `The term "∅" has type "UU" while it is expected to have type  "Type" (universe inconsistency: Cannot enforce UU.u0 <= Spartan_exercises.9 because Spartan_exercises.9 < UU.u0).`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a universe inconsistency.  You might get slightly more details with `Set Printing Universes.`.  The type `∑` is defined in [`Preamble.v`](https://github.com/UniMath/UniMath/blob/51310409eda6cf674f262529c20356210781e19b/UniMath/Foundations/Preamble.v#L180) to take its first argument as a type in `UU`.  Hence `∑ A:UU, (A → empty)` does not typecheck because `UU` is not a type in `UU`.  You can fix this error either by doing `Unset Universe Checking` (the equivalent of UniMath's `-type-in-type` flag that is globally passed), or, as you note, by replacing `UU` with `Type`.  However, as `empty` is in `UU` and not a strictly smaller universe, you cannot refine with `tpair _ empty _` without hitting the same universe inconsistency.  Note that `Unset Universe Checking` allows proofs of `False` (but they are relatively hard to find, which is why UniMath gets away with ignoring universe checking).  The more-confusing error message on `refine` probably comes from mixing record types defined with `-type-in-type` with code where universes are checked.

Comment: `Set Printing Universes`  does not yield any more information.

Comment: `Unset Universe Checking` indeed solves my problem when I replace `UU` by `Type`.

Comment: Note that the first error is thrown at the line `Theorem exercise_1_4: ...`. This does not yet have anything to do with the universe of `fill_me`, and indeed, is not solved by having `fill_me` work on a bigger universe. Also note that in UniMath, `UU` is defined as `UU := Type`.

Comment: So would there be a way to solve this without allowing universe inconsistencies (because those would allow for paradoxes)?

Comment: Also, the file `UniMath.Foundations.Preamble` has on one of the first lines `Definition UU := Type.` So why is there different behaviour when using `UU` vs `Type`?

Comment: I've updated my answer; I didn't want to bother compiling UniMath and was assuming that the error was on `exact`.

If you want to solve the problem without universe inconsistencies, you'll need to redefine all the types you want to sigma up from scratch as living in a smaller universe than `UU`.  The reason `UU` and `Type` behave differently is because Coq has [typical ambiguity](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2012/12/universe_polymorphism_and_typi.html) and each use of `Type` is given its own universe.  If `UU` were made universe-polymorphic, the same feature would apply to `UU`.

Comment: Who formulated the theorem, someone giving you the exercise or you yourself? It seems like the statement of the exercise is suboptimal.

Comment: @AndrejBauer According to https://github.com/UniMath/Schools/blob/master/2019-04-Birmingham/Part1_Spartan_Type_Theory/Spartan_exercises.v, it was Benedikt. I might ask him myself :-)

Comment: @JasonGross Thank you for the explanation. I believe I now understand what is happening here and why it goes wrong.

Comment: Benedikt lives dangerously, with universe checking turned off...